# Get Ribbon objects

Tags: c#, excel, ribbon

Is it possible to get items present in ribbon without using any addin or template based project in C#

I came through [a post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/vsto/thread/a12d3e02-4e19-4a16-aa7c-b866b922adb0) where user want to customize it .. I just want to get items present in ribbon

It may be a repeated question but i dont know any thing in this regard

Comment: are you looking for the contents of a custom ribbon or the default one? it appears from http://www.rondebruin.nl/xmlribbongroups.htm it is not possible to modify the standard ribbon.

Comment: @Pynner I am looking for the contents of default ribbon and i dont want to modify it

Comment: I am not sure how to get this information, however a bit of context as to why you need it may help me provide you with an alternate solution.

Comment: @Pynner actually i am making an elearning based appliction which automates excel :
A form will shows few task to the user like hide the macros command from ribbbon or expand the formula bar etc
And in return application will check whether it is done or not..

Comment: Ok i think I understand, you want the ribbon elements in order to execute the ribbon commands in c#. A slightly tedious way to get where you are going is to record a marco of all the button pushes on the ribbon. Going from vba code to c# isn't too hard (I have helped people with C# issues on this site despite never having written a line of C# code in my life).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add items like tabs, groups or buttons etc then There is an utility by name custom UI editor tool which you can obtain from openXMLdeveloper.org . it is an official tool because it is mentioned in Microsoft Help . after installing the tool you can open your excel file under "file -open" then the XML code you write in this editor will be linked to the excel file . After you write your XML code to add buttons , drop down lists, groups under your own tab which is all very easy to write in XML , you  save the XML file and open your excel file . you will find the items you added in XML file present in the ribbon under your new tab. Also search microsoft excel help "fluent ribbon excel 2007" for some sample XML code. Or search " customising the 2007 office fluent ribbon for developers (part 1 of 3) under Google. This article contains sample code which you can copy and paste in the UI editor tool.

If you want to make some built-in items appear on the ribbon or tabs appear then goto "file-options". Tick the items you want appear for eg. "Developer" tab.